# Android 4.2 and local network (192.168.x.x.)

Tags: security, android-networking, android-4.2-jelly-bean

I develop Android game and it connects to office server to log events. Like adb but over network.

That code works on all androids except Nexus 4 with Android 4.2.
It is only Android 4.2 device I have.

I read articles about new Android 4.2 security but have not seen that local network access is limited. I understand that it make sense but looking for confirmation that that there is such limitation or not.

Comment: How exactly do you log events? Is it a REST/similar web call, or are you using a different mechanism?

Comment: It is .NET application that listens for certain port like 15000. It shows when there is incoming connection. It is not REST. It is more like telnet.

Comment: Are you already requesting android.permission.Internet?

Comment: Sure. It works on all phones. 4.0, 2.3, 2.1. + Flurry works, Admob works. Debug version can't access office server. I think it could be a new security feature. To protect office open shader folders from Android apps.

Comment: That's strange. I went through the permissions map again, and it doesn't look like anything new has been added. Does logcat complain of anything? It usually does if it is a permissions issue.